# Docker-compose build gives error ADD failed: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, docker

I downloaded the code from my team's github repo, and I'm getting an error on running docker-compose build that my coworker is not getting. This code is a copy of another repo, just without some pieces of code, and that other code will build fine in docker.

I get the following error:
Step 4/22 : ADD package-lock.json /tmp/package-lock.json
ERROR: Service 'node' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder406470847/package-lock.json: no such file or directory

I'm not sure what's going on.

Dockerfile-local:

```
FROM node:10.15.3

LABEL maintainer xxx

#Install node dependencies
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
ADD package-lock.json /tmp/package-lock.json
RUN npm set progress=false
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/ && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /var/www/

#ignore list
COPY .eslintignore /var/www/.eslintignore
COPY .eslintrc.yml /var/www/.eslintrc.yml


#Docker
COPY Dockerfile /var/www/Dockerfile
COPY docker-compose.yml /var/www/docker-compose.yml


#Code
COPY package.json /var/www/package.json
COPY webpack.config.js /var/www/webpack.config.js
COPY bin /var/www/bin
COPY src /var/www/src
COPY test /var/www/test
COPY public /var/www/public

# build  
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN npm run build

#Port
EXPOSE 3000

#Start container
ENTRYPOINT ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: Does your local source tree in fact contain the `package-lock.json` file?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of something so obvious, thank you! Normally the package-lock.json file is already checked into the repo, but that was missed by the person who created it.